# Flattening a List of nested Json objects in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a list of Json Objects in this form:

```
[{'a': JsonObj()}, {'b':JsonObj()}, .... ]
```

How do I flatten the list into this form:

```
{'a': JsonObj(), 'b': JsonObj(), ...}
```

Note each field has a nested JsonObj as its value. I do not want to flatten those json objects.

I thought of appending it into a empty JsonObj but doesn't work.

```
val rStreetsJsonObj: JsObject = Json.obj()
for (routeS <- jsonList) {
      rStreetsJsonObj.+(routeS) // Gives error: expected arguments should be of the form (String, jsValue) not JsObject

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What lib are you using for json? Play?

Comment: yes, I am using Play framework

Comment: `list.foldLeft(Json.obj())(_ deepMerge _)`

Comment: @cchantep Thanks! If you add your answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.foldLeft(Json.obj())(_ deepMerge _)
```

This worked perfectly.

This answer is from a comment by @cchantep to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

**You can have a try this solution:**

**First**: you need convert **received string** to actual **JsArray**

the code maybe:

```
val jsArray = Json.parse("[{\"a\": 1}, {\"b\":1}]").asInstanceOf[JsArray]
```

**Play attention that `parse` method which return a JsValue type, actual it is a scala trait, the specific implement case class all extend it, such as JsArray**

**Second**: you can iterate the JsArray type, but **remember that it has not directly support the foreach method**.

But as a case class, you can access it's `value method`

In one word, the totally solution, you can have try it:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jsArray = Json.parse("[{\"a\": 1}, {\"b\":1}]").asInstanceOf[JsArray]
    var rStreetsJsonObj: JsObject = Json.obj()

    for (i <- jsArray.value) {
      val tmpObject = i.asInstanceOf[JsObject]
      rStreetsJsonObj = rStreetsJsonObj.++(tmpObject)
    }
    println(rStreetsJsonObj)
  }
}
```

**It will print the result**: `{"a":1,"b":1}`